# How to load image dynamically using thymleaf html in java?

Tags: java, html, image, thymeleaf

What is the syntax of the image to load dynamically using thymleaf html? I have attached the code and error.

// code

```
<div class="profilepic">
  <img th:src="@{profile.fetchProfilePhoto()}" />
 </div>
```

// error

```
 ERROR [http-nio-5555-exec-1] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/matrimony] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@{profile.fetchProfilePhoto()}" (template: "profile" - line 75, col 28)] with root cause
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@{profile.fetchProfilePhoto()}" (template: "profile" - line 75, col 28)
```

Comment: What Java-type is `me`? Is it placed by the controller into the `Model` via `model.addAttribute("profile", data)` somehow? If not, where is `profile` set?

Comment: @tucuxi Model->Profile->Under Profile(List<Media> medias))->Media model.I have added part of the response from profile

Comment: why do you expect `medias[0].cdnUrlT` to return something if there is no `cdnUrlT` in `me[0]`? Should it not read `me[0].cut`? I still have problems understanding the question: what does thymeleaf generate with your code, and what did you expect it to generate?

Comment: @tucuxi I want to know the syntax how do we load image url dynamically ?                        <img th:src="@{profile.medias[0].cdnUrlT}" />

Comment: Thanks for reply @tucuxi this code works for me <img th:src="@{${profile.fetchProfilePhoto()}}" />